# Rearrange dataframe, every n rows to columns, left to right, top down

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

A list of strings.

[image]

I want to arrange them into below format. Every 3 rows a group, from left to right, top to down:

[image]

By reshaping, I can only achieve below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [

"by Emily Dickinson",
"There is another sky,",
"Ever serene and fair,",
"And there is another sunshine,",
"Though it be darkness there;",
"Never mind faded forests, Austin,",
"Never mind silent fields -",
"Here is a little forest,",
"Whose leaf is ever green;",
"Here is a brighter garden,",
"Where not a frost has been;",
"In its unfading flowers",
"I hear the bright bee hum:",
"Prithee, my brother,",
"Into my garden come!"] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values,(5,3)))
```

[image]

What's the way to work it out? Thank you.

P.s. the "Row#" and "String" are provided only for clear reading. I want to achieve the rearrangement of content only.

Comment: Makes little sense. Display format and actual content are 2 different things. Most unclear which of the 2 you need.

Comment: @Julien, the "Row#" and "String" are provided just for clear reading of the question. I want to achieve the rearrangement of content only.

Comment: Well this makes things most unclear IMO. Please show your exact desired output in text form, not image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the reshape parameter and pass order parameter

```py
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values,(3,5),order='F'))
```